# CakePHP 4 and Authentication 2 Plugin - Remember Me Doesn't Create The Cookie

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp

I installed the authentication plugin on a fresh CakePHP 4 project. Enabled regarding the documentation and it works for session-based auth. I want to add remember me functionality, so added
`->add(new EncryptedCookieMiddleware(['CookieAuth'], Configure::read('Security.cookieKey')))` to the `$middlewareQueue` variable in `Application@middleware`. There is no any explanation how to generate the `cookieKey` actually, but I used a random string to test. Also added

```
 $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Cookie', [
        'fields' => $fields,
        'loginUrl' => '/users/login',
    ]);
```

remember me field is remember_me by default. So I added `<?= $this->Form->control('remember_me', ['type' => 'checkbox']); ?>` to the login form. I tried to check it and login, but it doesn’t add the cookie to the browser when I check with Chrome DevTools.

auth service config is like that in `getAuthenticationService`:

```
$service = new AuthenticationService();

        // Define where users should be redirected to when they are not authenticated
        $service->setConfig([
            'unauthenticatedRedirect' => Router::url([
                'prefix' => false,
                'plugin' => null,
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login',
            ]),
            'queryParam' => 'redirect',
        ]);

        $fields = [
            IdentifierInterface::CREDENTIAL_USERNAME => 'email',
            IdentifierInterface::CREDENTIAL_PASSWORD => 'password'
        ];
        // Load the authenticators. Session should be first.
        $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');

        // If the user is on the login page, check for a cookie as well.
        $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Cookie', [
            // 'rememberMeField' => 'remember_me',
            'fields' => $fields,
            'loginUrl' => '/users/login',
        ]);

        $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
            'fields' => $fields,
            'loginUrl' => Router::url([
                'prefix' => false,
                'plugin' => null,
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login',
            ]),
        ]);

        // Load identifiers
        $service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', compact('fields'));

        return $service;
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your complete authentication service configuration code look like?

Comment: I have added it to the question content. Could you check?

Comment: One thing that stands out is that your cookie and form authenticators are using different login URL configurations. Using the router would incorporate a possible base path that would be required in case your applications lives in a public subdirectory, ie `/myapp/users/login`. And even if there were no base path, your actual login URL could be different, the URL array could resolve to all kinds of URLs. So the question would be, what actually is your login endpoint URL?

Comment: I matched it with the form's one, and it worked indeed. Thanks!